# multiple worker processes calling HttpReceiveHttpRequest

Tags: c++, windows, http, process, worker

I want to use the Windows HTTP Server API 2.0 to wrap a RESTful web service around my legacy C++ code. I started with the sample app in MSDN, changed it to use the 2.0 APIs, and then split the app into three processes: a controller app that creates a named queue and url group and two identical worker processes that are child processes to the controller app. Both of the workers call HttpReceiveHttpRequest synchronously and wait for incoming requests. When they get a request, they call Sleep(5000) to wait 5 secs before calling HttpReceiveHttpRequest again. This allows me to fire off a second request from my browser while one worker process is still responding to the first request.

One worker process get the first request and waits. However, the second request is not processed by the second worker process as requested. Instead, the first worker process gets the second request. How can I get the incoming requests to be distributed across my worker processes? I expected each request would go to the first worker process waiting in HttpReceiveHttpRequest. If the first worker process was still busy processing a request, it would check the second worker process. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I realize how I describe HttpReceiveHttpRequest processing is a bit off. Each worker process in HttpReceiveHttpRequest is attempting to grab the next request off the same named queue. Only one of those processes will remove the first request. When the second request is placed in the queue, the second worker process should be the only one waiting for a request and, therefore, should remove and process the second request.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the problem. I was using Firefox with two tabs both with the same url (`http://127.0.0.1:80/test`) then doing Refresh All. Evidently, FF does not issue these two page requests at the same time but sends one, waits for the response, then sends the other, even though the animation in the tab makes it look like they are both being sent at the same time! If I use IE for one tab and FF for the other, then I get overlapping requests and my sample app uses both worker processes, as expected! Also works with two IE tabs. Only FF exhibits this odd behavior.